# Critical slowing down in Monte-Carlo algorithm for classical 2D Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, simulations, phase-transition, ising-model

Why do local updates (i.e. local spin flips) near the phase transition in MC algorithm for classical 2D Ising model are said to be not "effective" and lead to incorrect critical indices? I understand that it is somehow connected with infinite correlation length, but how exactly? Does it mean that near phase transition it takes infinite time for algorithm to achieve equilibrium distribution?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for what you're referring to?

Comment: Here, for instance, http://www.physics.buffalo.edu/phy411-506/topic2/topic2-lec4.pdf  Probably I don't understand the particular sentence "The  Metropolis  Monte  Carlo  method  generates  successive  configurations  of  spins,  but
this does not represent the real time evolution of a system of spins." So why do I need to consider cluster algorithms?

Comment: It is explained in the slides you cited in the previous comment that the critical slowing down is due to the divergence of the relaxation time when the critical temperature is approached. What is exactly that doesn't satisfy you in this explanation?

Comment: I don't understand why cluster algorithms (that flip group of spin in one Monte-Carlo step) improve convergence of the algorithm?

Comment: It seems that the link to the lecture that you posted no longer takes one to the lecture notes...